# Ancora não chama a seção referência

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma página do site que é responsável por apresentar os produtos do site. Pensem assim, você acessa a pagina e tem os botoes das categorias, cada vez que um botão de categoria é "active" ativado, os produtos daquela "seção" aparecem logo abaixo.

Eu já tive um problema alguns dias atras para descobrir como mudar o nome da h1 toda vez que uma categoria é chamada. Mas é passado.

Agora eu quero que a página comece na seção que tem o id "clsprod"

www.nomesite.com.br/produtos#clsprod

Mas veja bem, existe categorias que ainda não foram inseridos produtos, ou seja, quando o botão dela é clicado não aparece nenhum produto, mas isso é detalhe, não é problema!

O problema é que aquele link ali em cima deveria chamar a seção "clsprod" e iniciar a visualização apartir dali, mas ele não só não chama a ancora, como também não mostra todos os produtos (Botão "Todos os produtos" deveria ser padrão ao carregar a página)

Isso só acontece após eu rolara página até a seção "clsprod" e clicar em qualquer botão-categoria, aí ele chama a ancora e chama a visualização dos produtos.

É deselegante e eu já não sei mais o que invento pra resolver isso.

Tem algo que vocês saibam pra me ajudar a resovler esse problema? 
Se precisar de detalhes eu passo, e não vi motivo pra colocar o código porque é algo bem simples de entender.

Eu vejo que o código está todo ok e se não acusa erro.

Me ajudem, eu agradeço ^^

Comment: mostre o código

Comment: Amigo sem o seu código não tem como te responder por mais detalhes que vc ponha no relato... Edite sua pergunta e coloque seu CSS/HTML e JS